# How to load html string in Xamarin forms using SFSafariViewController?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, sfsafariviewcontroller

We currently use WebView to load html content.But the payment gateway loaded has Apple Pay button which only gets enabled in Safari browser.

We are kinda stuck because

**1.In iOS safari and sfsafaricontroller objects support Apple Pay

2.SFSafariViewController only supports URLs and that of type http:// and https://**

Can somebody suggest an alternative solution

Comment: set the user-agent so the site things you're using Safari

Comment: I have already set the user agent as request header.   httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 15_6_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.6 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1");

Comment: Without knowing anything about how the page is checking for Safari it’s difficult to recommend other options

Comment: Thanks Jason. The page is a third party payment. Not sure the logic used at their end to check for safari.